# Translation animation starts off screen instead of where it belongs

Tags: android, android-animation, floating-action-button

So we are trying to make an animation that moves the FAB before it disappears and opens a toolbar.  The problem is when I run the TranslationAnimation the FAB disappears and then slides in from off screen. the fromxDelta and fromYDelta don't ever behave the way I expect them too.

Can any one point out what I'm doing wrong or help me understand how this call works?

```
private void circularReveal(View toolbar, View fab) {
    final View view1 = toolbar;

    // get the center for the clipping circle
    int cx = (toolbar.getLeft() + toolbar.getRight()) / 2;
    int cy = (toolbar.getTop() + toolbar.getBottom()) / 2;

    // get the final radius for the clipping circle
    int finalRadius = Math.max(toolbar.getWidth(), toolbar.getHeight());

    // create the animator for this view (the start radius is zero)
    final SupportAnimator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(toolbar, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);
    //todo create an animation to move the fab.

    TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
                                                                Animation.ABSOLUTE , -100f,
                                                                Animation.ABSOLUTE , 0f,
                                                                Animation.ABSOLUTE , -100f);
    translateAnimation.setDuration(2000L);
    translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    Animation.AnimationListener animationListener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            view1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            anim.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    };
    translateAnimation.setAnimationListener(animationListener);
    fab.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
}
```

*EDIT*  I cleaned up some variable names in the code snippet.

Comment: how do you call this method? circularReveal(fab, toolbar); ? Because you are applying the translateAnimation on your View that is named toolbar.

Comment: The method is called from the 
      the onClickListener  which is being set on the Fab in the fragments onCreatView().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So we are trying to make an animation that moves the FAB before it
>   disappears and opens a toolbar.

Your code reads the other way around. It looks like you are applying a TranslateAnimation on your View named 'toolbar' , and using a circular Reveal on your FloatingActionButton.

Anyways I guess you are trying to achieve something like this :

```
private void circularReveal(final View view, View toolbar) {

    // get the center for the clipping circle
    int cx = (toolbar.getLeft() + toolbar.getRight()) / 2;
    int cy = (toolbar.getTop() + toolbar.getBottom()) / 2;

    // get the final radius for the clipping circle
    int finalRadius = Math.max(toolbar.getWidth(), toolbar.getHeight());

    // create the animator for this view (the start radius is zero)
    final Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(toolbar, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);

    view.animate()
            .translationX(-100)
            .translationY(-100)
            .setDuration(2000)
            .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  // set this to INVISIBLE if you want your FAB to dissapear 
                    anim.start();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            });

}
```

This moves the FAB a little to the left and up before the toolbar reveals and the FAB dissapears.

Call this method with FAB as first, and ToolBar as second parameter.

I left out the [TranslateAnimation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html) and used [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) because a TranslateAnimation is not really moving the view but only the pixels on the screen, while ViewPropertyAnimator changes the actual positioning of the View. The issue with TranslateAnimation is that you can still click on the old position where the FAB was and it will still trigger the FAB OnClickListener.

Comment: Thanks I cleaned up those variable names.  I tried out the ViewPropertyAnimator  as in your example and it made the fab disappear from the screen only to reappear in the new spot after the two seconds were up.

Comment: So I had to set the attribute android:animateLayoutChanges="true"  in the two xml parents of my fragment layout xml.   once I did that the animation showed up correctly.  Thanks for your help.